# Least upper bound on set of positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, order-theory, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Short version: **Does the Loewner order have the least-upper-bound property?**

Long version:

Suppose I have a finite set of finite-dimensional positive semidefinite matrices $\mathcal{M}$. That is, we have $M\ge 0$ for all $M\in\mathcal{M}$.  Here "$\ge$" is the [Loewner order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order), which is a partial order on matrices where we say $A \ge B$ when $v^*(A-B)v \ge 0$ for all vectors $v$ (and where "${}^*$" is the adjoint).

An "upper bound" on the set $\mathcal{M}$ is a matrix $A$ satisfying $A \ge M$ for all $M\in\mathcal{M}$.

**For any set $\mathcal{M}$, is there necessarily a matrix $\bar{M}$ that provides a *least* upper bound in the sense that $\bar{M} \le A$ for all upper bounds $A$?**

It seems relevant that the space of upper bounds is convex, i.e., if $A$ and $B$ are upper bounds then so is $C_\lambda = \lambda A + (1-\lambda)B$ for any $\lambda\in [0,1]$.  However, it's easy to check that for any two upper bounds $A$ and $B$ there need not be a choice $\lambda$ such that $C_\lambda \le A$ and $C_\lambda \le B$.

Comment: Although the essence of this question is identical to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032632/the-set-of-self-adjoint-operators-over-a-hilbert-space-doesnt-form-a-lattice/2036853#2036853) the wording is sufficiently different that the answer could not be found through Google.  The key term was "lattice", which is a partial order with the [least-upper-bound property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property).  I'm self-marking as duplicate.

Comment: "The Loewner order does not have the least-upper-bound property, and therefore does not form a lattice." says [this reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_order)

Comment: Jean, I edited the Wikipedia article to add that sentence today. Richard, I link to that question in the answer below. Again: that question was nearly impossible to find without knowing what a "lattice" is.

Answer (score 1):

No.  A complete explanation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2036853/36155) for which I quote a relevant counterexample: Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be $2\times 2$ and project onto the respective basis elements: $$M_1=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, \qquad M_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Then it's clear that the identity $I$ is an upper bound ($I \ge M_1, I\ge M_2$).  Furthermore, you can't choose a matrix strictly smaller than  $I$, i.e., no upper bound $A$ on the set $\mathcal{M}=\{M_1,M_2\}$ could satisfy $A\le I$ (except $A=I$).

But one can also check that the matrix $$B=\begin{pmatrix}1+1/\sqrt{2}&1\\1&1+1/\sqrt{2}\end{pmatrix}$$ satisfies $B\ge M_1$ and $B\ge M_2$, yet $B$ and $I$ are incomparable.  Therefore, no least upper bound exists.